# The trackbars in my code are not displaying any values?

Tags: python, opencv

I am following a tutorial to detect specific colours using OpenCV HSV. To identify the correct HSV values I have (as shown in the tutorial) added trackbars to detect the upper and lower values for HSV. All works OK but I don't get any values showing on my trackbars.

I am doing this on a Macbook Pro OS 10.13.6 using PyCharm 2018.2.4. When checked in terminal in my virtual environment OpenCV is showing as 4.0.0-dev, python version is 3.7.1

Here is my code:

```
# script for detecting colours with OpenCV using HSV (Hue, Saturation, Value)
# credits https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMFhjir4WgQ

import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    #any function here
    pass

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #captures video from the main camera,

# create a trackbar window to help tune the detection and find the HSV
cv2.namedWindow("Trackbars")

# create the trackbars for each HSV value
cv2.createTrackbar("L-H", "Trackbars", 0, 180, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("L-S", "Trackbars", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("L-V", "Trackbars", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("U-H", "Trackbars", 180, 180, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("U-S", "Trackbars", 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("U-V", "Trackbars", 255, 255, nothing)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read() # read each video frame
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) # converts BGR colour to HSV

    l_h = cv2.getTrackbarPos("L-H", "Trackbars")
    l_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos("L-S", "Trackbars")
    l_v = cv2.getTrackbarPos("L-V", "Trackbars")
    u_h = cv2.getTrackbarPos("U-H", "Trackbars")
    u_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos("U-S", "Trackbars")
    u_v = cv2.getTrackbarPos("U-V", "Trackbars")

    # set upper and lower red values
    lower_red = np.array([l_h, l_s, l_v])
    upper_red = np.array([u_h, u_s, u_v])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red) # identify red in frame

    #cv2.imshow("Frame", frame) # opens a window to show original video being captured
    resize = cv2.resize(mask, (960, 540))
    cv2.imshow("Mask", resize) # opens a window to show the mask

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it helps, but you the Hue should be in 0 - 178 range, not 0 - 180.
So i d change it from 0 - 179 for the lowest values, and 179 - 179 to highest value